# how to preserve custom constraint with add "reset to suggested constraints" button

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

i had added layout constraints with "add missing constraints" button. Next time i want to change my default constraints but my constraints is missing.

My cases

1. Default constraint of UITextView  is "height = 30". i want to change "height >= 30". i had edited this constraint but when i clicked "reset to suggested constraints" button, my constraint change that "height = 30" again.
2. if i had deleted default constraint and then i clicked "reset to suggested constraints" button, constraint is added again.

How can i preserve my custom constraints with default constraints. because when i add new control to layout, i have to use "reset to suggested constraints" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset to suggested constraints delete all your constraints from your selected view and add new random ones. I don't recommend you that because you don't know how the view will resize with different devices. 
Just add manually the constraints according your UI requirements.
Or...if you don't know how works autolayout... click on clear all constraints, add suggested constraints and then modify your contraints using interface builder and  don't press again "reset to suggested constraints".